# How to edit CodeIgniter native SMTP connect function to allow connections through proxy

Tags: php, codeigniter, proxy, smtp

I am working on a project on my local machine using the Codeigniter framework. I am connecting to an outside SMTP service through the native Email.php library in CI and this works fine on my remove dev server.

Unfortunately I am running into connection issues on my localhost due to a corporate proxy. It requires credentials as well.

So far I have isolated the connection issue in the following *native* CI function in Email.php:

```
/**
 * SMTP Connect
 *
 * @access  protected
 * @param   string
 * @return  string
 */
protected function _smtp_connect()
{
    $ssl = NULL;
    if ($this->smtp_crypto == 'ssl')
        $ssl = 'ssl://';
    $this->_smtp_connect = fsockopen($ssl.$this->smtp_host,
                                    $this->smtp_port,
                                    $errno,
                                    $errstr,
                                    $this->smtp_timeout);

    if ( ! is_resource($this->_smtp_connect))
    {
        $this->_set_error_message('lang:email_smtp_error', $errno." ".$errstr);
        return FALSE;
    }

    $this->_set_error_message($this->_get_smtp_data());

    if ($this->smtp_crypto == 'tls')
    {
        $this->_send_command('hello');
        $this->_send_command('starttls');
        stream_socket_enable_crypto($this->_smtp_connect, TRUE, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT);
    }

    return $this->_send_command('hello');
}
```

I need to find a way to open this connection through the proxy and supply credentials. I'll make a quick conditional switch so this will be interchangeable with the remote server which wouldn't need it.

Thank you very much for any assistance on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. I have posted the solution here:

https://github.com/pkandathil/ci_proxy_email

You have to extended the CI_Email library to accept a proxy. Then instead of using fsockopen I use stream_socket_client and specify the proxy in there.

```
protected function _smtp_connect() {
$ssl = NULL;
if ($this->smtp_crypto == 'ssl')
  $ssl = 'ssl://';
$CI =& get_instance();
if(!empty($this->proxy)) {
  $context = stream_context_create(['http' => ['proxy' => 'tcp://' . $this->proxy]]);
  $this->_smtp_connect = stream_socket_client($ssl.$this->smtp_host . ':' . $this->smtp_port,
                $errno,
                $errstr,
                $this->smtp_timeout,
                STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT,
                $context);
}
else {
  $this->_smtp_connect = fsockopen($ssl.$this->smtp_host,
                $this->smtp_port,
                $errno,
                $errstr,
                $this->smtp_timeout);
}
if ( ! is_resource($this->_smtp_connect))
{
  $this->_set_error_message('lang:email_smtp_error', $errno." ".$errstr);
  return FALSE;
}
$this->_set_error_message($this->_get_smtp_data());
if ($this->smtp_crypto == 'tls')
{
  $this->_send_command('hello');
  $this->_send_command('starttls');
  stream_socket_enable_crypto($this->_smtp_connect, TRUE, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT);
}
return $this->_send_command('hello');
```

}
}

Comment: Sorry the above code does not work. You cannot set an http context for an SMTP request. It has been accepted incorrectly.